# UPDATE using SELECT as WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run an Update where the WHERE statement consists of 2 SELECTS, is this at all close to how you do that?

```
UPDATE Requests SET Response=1 WHERE 
sender=SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) and 
Reciever = SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?
```

Thank!

Comment: Use update with a JOIN.

Comment: @Mihai I wouldn't use join in every situation, especially not if he's only accessing one column of the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parentheses, that's all.

```
UPDATE Requests SET Response=1 WHERE 
sender = (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) and 
receiver = (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?);
```

Comment: also note that the username must be unique, else this statement is prone to errors